# Correct placement of values in a triangle

Tags: trigonometry

**Task**
In a right angled triangle, the shortest side is 8.0 centimeter. We know that for the smallest angle $\alpha^{\circ}$, $2.4=\frac{1}{\tan{\alpha^{\circ}}}$. Determine the largest side $c$.

Ok, I go by feeling and decide that the opposing cathetus is eight centimeters long, and that $\alpha^{\circ}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2.4}\right)$, $ \alpha^{\circ}$ is the angle opposite the opposing cathetus. Then I calculate the largest side $c$,

$$\alpha^{\circ}=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2.4}\right) =22.62^{\circ}\:$$

$$c=\frac{8}{\sin{22.62^{\circ}}}=21 cm$$

I get the correct answer, my problem is that I get it by going by feeling. How should I interpret texts giving me problems with triangles, e.g. **how do you find which side in the triangle is the smallest, and depending on the length of the sides in the triangle, which angle that is the smallest - and so on?** (And not only placements of values in a right-angled triangle, but in triangles overall).

Comment: What is $v$????

Comment: @JanEerland Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In a right triangle, $\triangle\text{ABC}$ we know:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left|\text{C}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2\\
\\
\angle\alpha^\circ+\angle\beta^\circ+90^\circ=180^\circ
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Say, the shortest side is $\left|\text{A}\right|=8$ and $\frac{12}{5}=\frac{1}{\tan\angle\alpha^\circ}$, so we get:

$$\tan\angle\alpha^\circ=\frac{\left|\text{B}\right|}{\left|\text{A}\right|}=\frac{\left|\text{B}\right|}{8}=\frac{5}{12}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left|\text{B}\right|=\frac{5\cdot8}{12}=\frac{10}{3}\tag2$$

So, we get:

$$\left|\text{C}\right|^2=8^2+\left(\frac{10}{3}\right)^2=\frac{676}{9}\space\implies\space\left|\text{C}\right|=\sqrt{\frac{676}{9}}=\frac{26}{3}\tag3$$

Comment: My question was: 'How do you find which side in the triangle is the smallest, and depending on the length of the sides in the triangle, which angle that is the smallest - and so on?'

Comment: @theHumbleOne Well, now you can see